# "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, each

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item-title a").each(function(index) { 
        var yaz = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api-metrica.yandex.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?end-date=today&ids=ga%3A35416355&dimensions=ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:pageviews&filters=ga:pagePath=='+yaz+'&start-date=2015-10-25&oauth_token=AQAAAAAVs-uLAASpEAf-MmJK_kHgpU9Fwv8WArM',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){  
                $(this).append(data.rows);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Console:** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

What is problem?
Please Help.

Comment: not suer if this matters but did you mean to have `pagePath==` with two equals?

Comment: @Intervalia this is metrica url parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the `this` context in `success` callback.
It does not point to the `jQuery` object inside the callback as you expect. It will refer to the current context.

```
success: function(data){  
    $(this).append(data.rows);;
}
```

Save the context of `this` outside the `success` and reuse it.

```
var cachedThis = this;

$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(data){  
      $(cachedThis).append(data.rows);;
   }
   ...
});
```

Instead you can use the `bind` method to lock the context.

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(data){  
       $(this).append(data.rows);;
   }.bind(this)
   ...
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it!! He could also just put the variable yaz in there `$(yaz).append(data.rows);`